# Moq.netcore failing for .Net Core RC2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, moq, .net-core-rc2

So I had a solution working on .Net RC1 with Moq, and I've upgraded to RC2 which I found that Moq.netcore was created to run on the new platform.

I added aspnet-contrib to my NuGet.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="contrib" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnet-contrib/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I've added moq.netcore to my project.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "type": "platform"
  },
  "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-173361-36",
  "moq.netcore": "4.4.0-beta8",
  "xunit": "2.1.0"
},

"testRunner": "xunit",

"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "dotnet5.6",
      "portable-net451+win8"
    ]
  }
}
```

Basically I followed [Cli Testing Abstractions UnitTests](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/c01331f2f988fbbd2f6b6746b9318e8e5bdf9e63/test/TestingAbstractions/Microsoft.Extensions.Testing.Abstractions.UnitTests/project.json) and I get the following error when instantiatin a Mock object:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : 
  Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

  Stack Trace:
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.MethodWithInvocationGenerator.BuildProxiedMethodBody(MethodEmitter emitter, ClassEmitter class, ProxyGenerationOptions options, INamingScope namingScope)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.MethodGenerator.Generate(ClassEmitter class, ProxyGenerationOptions options, INamingScope namingScope)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.CompositeTypeContributor.ImplementMethod(MetaMethod method, ClassEmitter class, ProxyGenerationOptions options, OverrideMethodDelegate overrideMethod)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.CompositeTypeContributor.Generate(ClassEmitter class, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateType(String name, Type[] interfaces, INamingScope namingScope)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.ObtainProxyType(CacheKey cacheKey, Func`3 factory)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
       at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type mockType, ICallInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments)
       at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__19_0()
       at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject()
       at Moq.MockDefaultValueProvider.ProvideDefault(MethodInfo member)
       at Moq.QueryableMockExtensions.FluentMock[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 setup)
       at lambda_method(Closure )
       at Moq.Mock.GetInterceptor(Expression fluentExpression, Mock mock)
       at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass57_0`2.<SetupGet>b__0()
```

Comment: Add more components to project.json starting with "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource"?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Edit:** this trick is no longer necessary with [Moq > 4.6.38-alpha](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/4.6.38-alpha):

```
"dependencies" {
  "Moq": "4.6.38-alpha"
}
```

---

This bug is likely caused by the fact `System.Diagnostics.TraceSource` is not directly referenced by the moq package and thus is not imported transitively in your project. To work around this limitation, you can explicitly reference the `System.Diagnostics.TraceSource` package:

Here's how we use it in our OAuth2 validation middleware tests project, that runs on both .NET Desktop and .NET Core:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "warningsAsErrors": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": { "target": "project" },
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-build10015",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
    "xunit": "2.1.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "type": "platform", "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702" },
        "moq.netcore": "4.4.0-beta8",
        "System.Diagnostics.TraceSource": "4.0.0-rc2-24027"
      },

      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    },

    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-rc2-24027",
        "Moq": "4.2.1312.1622"
      }
    }
  },

  "testRunner": "xunit"
}
```

https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions/blob/master/test/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation.Tests/project.json#L21

Comment: Hmm... I tried System.Diagnostics, but yeah this makes sense. Seems a little weird, but I'll chalk it up to Moq being in beta. Thanks for the help.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.TraceSource can be found in the Nuget Package Manager is Include prerelease is checked.

Comment: Edited to mention that this trick is no longer needed with Moq 4.6.38-alpha.